# Reading Issue Fields via Workfront-API

Tags: workfront-api

Please tell me how to read Issue Fields like resolveProjectID & resolveTaskID:

****.workfront.com/attask/api/OPTASK/search?id=5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa
returns:

```
{"data":
  [{"ID":"5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa",
  "name":"test-dev-issue","objCode":"OPTASK",
  "plannedCompletionDate":"2018-11-27T00:00:00:000+0200",
  "status":"NEW",
  "primaryAssignment":null}]
}
```

According to the API-Explorer guide (https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/220633507-API-Explorer), resolveProjectID & resolveTaskID should be located within OPTASK fields. I couldn't find anything helpful yet within their documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The search you're executing will work, but if you know the ID of the record you're retrieving then you should call it directly (/api/v9.0/OPTASK/5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa).

The return value is, by default, a small set of fields providing some basic data. If you want more fields, add a parameter (fields=).

Comment: using /attask/api/OPTASK/search?id=5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa&fields=resolveProjectID, it throws the following error: {"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"APIModel V2_0 does not support field resolveProjectID (OpTask)"}}

Comment: using /attask/api/OPTASK//5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa/fields=resolveProjectID, it returns the previous json (which doesn't include resolveProjectID). Please, can you share any hints on how to use the parameter fields=** ?

Comment: resolveProjectID is a field that was added way past API v2.0. You should always explicitly call the API version you want. We're up to 9.0. Your call should be to /attask/api/v9.0/OPTASK/search?id=5bf801f101b144a12aabb51f2c068caa&fields=resolveProjectID